# Calculating Perfect Squares of all numbers up to a given number?

Tags: java, methods

I want to write a program that finds the square of all numbers up to a user inputed number. For example, if the user inputs 5, then the program outputs 1,4,9,16,25.

This is what I've tried.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PerfectSquares {

    public void numberInput(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int choice = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i =0;i<choice;i++){
            choice=choice*choice;
        }
        System.out.println("The squares are" + choice);     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PerfectSquares input = new PerfectSquares();
        input.numberInput();
    }

}
```

The output gives me only one number which is not what I am looking for.I am new to JAVA and programming but my understanding is that you should try to create methods outside the main and then create objects to call the methods inside the main. So I am trying to create a method called numberInput and then in the main I try to call it. Please correct me if this is the wrong approach.

Comment: Where is your println statement? Is it *inside* of the for loop, where it will be repeatedly called? Or is it outside of the loop where it will only be called *once*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, the issue for your outcome is that the loop is updating the same number.

```
Import java.util.Scanner;
public class PerfectSquares {

public void numberInput(int max){
    List<Integer> squares = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0;i<max;i++) {
        squares.add(i^2);
    }
    System.out.println("The squares are: " +  String.join(squares, ", ");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int choice = sc.nextInt();
    PerfectSquares input = new PerfectSquares();
    input.numberInput(choice);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you please explain what is (into max) and what is List<Integer>. Are you creating an array? What are the arrow parenthesis <>? Also what is String.join(squares, ". ") doing?

Comment: Into was a typo, it should have been int.  a java.util.List is a java.util.Collection extension. They are a very useful group of classes and interfaces which deal with numerous peices of data of the same type. The <> are the generics declaration which in this case mean that only objects of that type can be in the list.

Comment: @Nabeel Eh I recommend that you read the Java docs for Collections and String.